# Conditionally render react components based on URL in existing .NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core, react-router

I have an existing .NET Core MVC project which is currently using jQuery and Knockout.js for it's interactive features. I would like to move away from this to a more modern approach. I have seen that .NET Core has new ReactJS project templates but I am not in a position to start from scratch so I am trying to add ReactJS to specific pages in my MVC project and over time I will remove all the legacy jQuery and Knockout code.

I have managed to get react, webpack and babel all set up and building when running `npm run build` and I can display a simple component on a page. However, I want to conditionally render a React component based on which page I'm on. Currently I have an existing MVC page/view under the URL `/Pricing/Sales` and I'd like to replace this view with a React component whilst maintaining my website layout from `_layout.cshtml` (header, footer etc).

I was expecting to be able to place my target `<div>` in the existing view and use `react-router` to detect the current URL and display the appropriate component but I can't get it to work. I'm just getting the following error:

> Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Here's my code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('reactRoot')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SalesIndex from './components/pricing/sales/SalesIndex';

const App = () => {
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Pricing/Sales" component={SalesIndex} />
    </Switch>
}

export default App;
```

**components/pricing/sales/SalesIndex.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const SalesIndex = () => <div>Hello from SalesIndex!</div>

export default SalesIndex;
```

**MVC View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Sale>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Sales";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-pricing page-pricing-sales">
        <h2>Sales</h2>
        <hr />

        <div id="reactRoot"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MVC Configure**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

    if (env.IsProduction())
    {
        //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**Webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: './Scripts/src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is perfectly clear. You forgot `return`:

```
const App = () => {
  return ( // <-- you are missing this
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Pricing/Sales" component={SalesIndex} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

You could also write

```
const App = () =>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/Pricing/Sales" component={SalesIndex} />
  </Switch>
```

with optional parens if you like that kind of thing.

Comment: Ohhh, I'm an idiot. Thank you. Sorry, I am new to React and thought it was doing the switch but failing to match the URL and then looking for a default/fallback route and not finding one. Added the return and I'm now seeing my component rendering as expected. Thank you again!